# I have comma seperated column and need to get most common values from them in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have comma separated value in mysql table field and want to get most common value amongst them.

i.e. I have a table name is `A`, In which there are two fields `id` and `available_values`.

```
 id    available_values
 ---   -----------------
 1     3,5,7,9
 2     3,5
 3     5,9
```

In above example there are value 5 exist in all rows so i need to get this value(mean - 5), because this is available in every records.

Please help to find out the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your data model and include a table with one row per id and available value.  Comma separated lists are not a SQLish way of storing data.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to include another table with one row per id and your values. But you can use `REGEXP` to achieve the output :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE
available_values REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', replace(5,',','|'),')(,|$)')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($keysValue,available_values)
```

example

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($keysValue,columnsName)
```

Comment: Did you try this? please try and then rate or vote this.